# pdf font and graph formatting (win.graph)

Tags: r, graph, fonts, pdf-generation

I recently came upon a problem in R which in that combination I have tried to solve and also searched for in the internet, but which I could not solve yet. I hope someone can help me.

I run R(x64) on Windows 7. The graphic device itself automatically uses Arial as font, and when I save graphs as bitmap the "font" naturally remains as it is. However, I prefer saving graphs as pdf, in which case the font in the resulting pdf is exchanged with Helvetica when I simply save via the GUI save button.

I found a solution for that in the internet, using the Arial afm-Files and pdf("Test_Auto.pdf", family = "Arial"), which resulted in a pdf using Arial as font---so far so good.

Now I also often have to/want to change the graph layout using win.graph, and that is where the problems start. Here is an example:

```
Arial <- Type1Font(family = "Arial", metrics = c("C:/R_Fonts/ArialPlain.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialBold.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialItalic.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialBoldItalic.afm"))
pdfFonts(Arial = Arial)

setwd("C:/PDFCrop")
D1<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,6,3),3,2)
D2<-matrix(c(1,2,3,5,3,1),3,2)

#pdf("Test_Auto.pdf", family = "Arial")
win.graph(8.3,12,12)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=TRUE))
plot(D1,type="l",main="Gobble R")
plot(D2,type="l",main="Gobble R")
#dev.off()
```

Now this code as it is works to create a graph that looks like I want it to look, but I have to save the graph manually (File->save as) and then I get Helvetica as font in the pdf.

Alternatively I can change the lower part in

```
pdf("Test_Auto.pdf", family = "Arial")
#win.graph(8.3,12,12)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=TRUE))
plot(D1,type="l",main="Gobble R")
plot(D2,type="l",main="Gobble R")
dev.off()
```

And that produces a pdf-file that actually uses Arial, but the graph has other dimensions as I was intending. When using both together I get a pdf which "cannot be opened because it does't contain any pages" (though it is not 0KB in size).

Is there any way to get this to work, or an alternative to win.graph which I can use between pdf() and dev.off()?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Set the dimensions of the pdf device. Trying to mix two different devices seems a prescription for insanity.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, I'm sorry, I was so stupid!

During all that I completely overlooked, that the pdf-device has its own size parameters.

```
Arial <- Type1Font(family = "Arial", metrics = c("C:/R_Fonts/ArialPlain.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialBold.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialItalic.afm", "C:/R_Fonts/ArialBoldItalic.afm"))
pdfFonts(Arial = Arial)

setwd("C:/PDFCrop")
D1<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,6,3),3,2)
D2<-matrix(c(1,2,3,5,3,1),3,2)

pdf("Test_Auto.pdf", width=8.3, height=12, family = "Arial")
#win.graph(8.3,12,12)
layout(matrix(c(1,2),1,2,byrow=TRUE))
plot(D1,type="l",main="Gobble R")
plot(D2,type="l",main="Gobble R")
dev.off()
```

Thank you for the hint, DWin